# Crystal Report stops after uploading database on hosting website

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application using c# and SQL Server database, I used the Crystal Report and it works fine when I was using local server, but when I uploaded the database to a hosting site, the reports no longer work because the connection is invalid with the database.
I have the connection string I got from my hosting site but I don't know where to use it for Crystal Report.
This is the connection string:
 `@"Data Source=SQL5104.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=db_a73b95_data;User Id=db_a73b95_data_admin;Password=XXXX"`

Comment: See following : file:///C:/Users/jwarburg/Downloads/SAP-Crystal-Step-by-Step-guide-Connect-to-MS-SQL-Server.pdf

Comment: Please kindly check it with your provider about connection string that you need to use. Make sure that your provider also support Crystal Report. For CR hosting, I use Asphostportal, you can consider them if your current provider doesn't support it.

Comment: Ok jdweng, I will check thank you a lot